# How to Make group notifications by app?

Tags: swift, ios7, apple-push-notifications

how to group the notification based on the app's type.

i don't need any explanation for group notification by app.

how to categories and group the notification with in the app functionality.

when i receive more than one notification in a particular type,
 For ex:

1. Application-A,Type-1,Notification1
2. Application-A,Type-1,Notification2
3. Application-A,Type-1,Notification3
4. Application-A,Type-2,Notification1
5. Application-A,Type-2,Notification2

i want to group the Notification based on the type not by the Application.

thanks in advance